# Extracting pandas DataFrame from function to a global variable

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas and python.

I am trying to extract pandas DataFrame that I create in a function to a global variable which I could use in future functions.

My code:

```
def initialize_analyticsreporting():
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)

    analytics = build('analyticsreporting', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

    return analytics


def get_report(analytics):

    return analytics.reports().batchGet(
        body={
            'reportRequests': [
                {
                    'viewId': VIEW_ID,
                    'pageSize': 100000,
                    'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '7daysAgo', 'endDate': 'yesterday'}],
                    'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}],
                    'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:country'}, {'name': 'ga:hostname'}, {'name': 'ga:pagePathLevel1'}, {'name': 'ga:pagePathLevel2'}, {'name': 'ga:keyword'}, {'name': 'ga:adMatchedQuery'}, {'name': 'ga:operatingSystem'}, {'name': 'ga:hour'}, {'name': 'ga:exitPagePath'}]
                }]
        }
    ).execute()


def print_response(response):
    list = []
    for report in response.get('reports', []):
        columnHeader = report.get('columnHeader', {})
        dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get('dimensions', [])
        metricHeaders = columnHeader.get(
            'metricHeader', {}).get('metricHeaderEntries', [])
        rows = report.get('data', {}).get('rows', [])

    for row in rows:
        dict = {}
        dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
        dateRangeValues = row.get('metrics', [])
        for header, dimension in zip(dimensionHeaders, dimensions):
            dict[header] = dimension

        for i, values in enumerate(dateRangeValues):
            for metric, value in zip(metricHeaders, values.get('values')):
                if ',' in value or '.' in value:
                    dict[metric.get('name')] = float(value)
                else:
                    dict[metric.get('name')] = int(value)

        list.append(dict)

    df = pd.DataFrame(list)
    return df


def main():
    analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
    response = get_report(analytics)
    print_response(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

At this point after `main()` is called I can either `print(df)` inside `print_response' function. But I want to be able to call the`df`in my`print_response` function outside of the function, like to make df be accessible globally.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Why not assign `df` to a global variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply assign to a global variable inside the function or return the value and assign it as you call the function. You can declare global variables beforehand or in the function for the first time, but the keyword `global` needs to be used.

```
df1 = None

def f():
    global df1, df2
    df1 = pd.DataFrame()
    df2 = pd.DataFrame()
    return pd.DataFrame()

df3 = f()
# Now df 1, 2 and 3 are all global DataFrames
```

Whether you **should** use global variables is another topic. You can just return whatever from the function and pass it to other functions just as well.

```
def f() -> pd.DataFrame:
    return pd.DataFrame()

def g(df: pd.DataFrame):
    # Do stuff with df

def main():
    df = f()
    g(df)
```

Comment: Thank you! What would be the downsides of using a global variable?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis Search and you'll find many resources. To me, global variables outside the main script should be a rare occurrence. Functions should be pure, meaning they only manipulate input to produce output with no side-effects. That's the most clear way of writing them and the easiest to debug when something goes wrong. If you are just writing a script, assigning return values to variables in your script is totally fine. But wrapping them to a main function should make no difference. I wouldn't worry **too** much about it if it doesn't affect other people, but keep it in mind. Have fun!